# Google Maps Geocoding API Stopped working (simple?)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The code below has worked fine for quite some time but just stopped working. I did recently move to a new server but that wouldn't affect anything here, would it?? All I'm trying to get is lat/lng, but now it's returning nothing. Any help is appreciated!

```
$address = '127+East+Redlands+Blvd+92373';

$geocode = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address ='.$address.'&key=MY KEY WAS HERE');

$output = json_decode($geocode);

$latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Comment: You might have http referer enabled which is for your previous domain or ip addresses enabled which is for your previous server.

Comment: For a web service, that would be IP address

Comment: I'm not using HTTP_REFERRER on the page. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was related to the server move after all. The new server had
[allow_url_fopen] disabled in php.ini. Enabled that and all is well again. :D